# What is the correct order to watch My Hero Academia (Boku No Hero Academia) including movies?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Does anyone know the correct order to watch *My Hero Academia*? Every site I try has different ways to watch it, and that confuses me.

So, can anyone tell me the *actual* order to watch it, including the movies?

Answer (score 2):

Found below recommended viewing order:

- Season 1 (13 episodes)
- Season 2 (25 episodes)
- **My Hero Academia: Two Heroes**
- Season 3 (25 episodes)
- Season 4 (25 episodes)
- **My Hero Academia: Heroes Rising**
- Season 5 (25 episodes)
- **My Hero Academia: World Heroes' Mission**

Source: https://www.samuel-official.jp/hiroaka-eiga-junban

It's been a while since I finished watching until S5, so I did not check the accuracy of above.

Comment: Note that this order is the same as the broadcast date, which is usually the most logical.